# Need to view time series monthly in Superset Time Series - Line Chart

Tags: postgresql, apache-superset

I need to view time series monthly. I'm able to get the chart with Time Grain set as "Time Column" but when I select "month" I get the following error.

> (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) function date_trunc(unknown, unknown) is not unique LINE 1: SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', 'datetime') AS __timestamp, ^ HINT: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.

[image]

Comment: What type is `datetime` in your database? This looks like an error when PG can't resolve the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

If the head count is an integer data type in the DB table, and assuming datetime is the name of your date column, try using count and then group by the head count column.